# Gradle failOnError for default ant task

Tags: ant, gradle, failonerror

Ive the following gradle snippet.

```
defaultTasks = ['init', 'run']

task init() {

    ant {
        property(file: 'run.properties')
    }
    ant.importBuild "build.xml"

}
```

The issue is, whenever the deault task run executed from my build.xml fails gradle doesnt recognize this as a failure. Is there a way I can set a failOnError for the default task?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but this might work:

```
ant.failOnError = true
```